# Google Sheet Filter View Sorting gets turned off when I edit a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I just converted a sheet to use filter views. It has a language column, and in this example I am filtering to show only Hebrew words.

[image]

I added "Sort A -> Z" in the "custom" column, by clicking the three-line-funnel looking thing on the "custom" cell, and setting sort. This I assume is sorting based on the filter view. It does sort the rows by that column. *However*, say I change a value from "badal" to "hadal", it should change its position in the alphabetic sorting. Well, it doesn't. The sorting gets turned off, the column no longer has a filter on it after I edit a cell in that column, and the row never jumps to the new position. So it appears sorting doesn't save on the filter view? And every time I want to see it sorted again, I have to click a few times to turn it on?

Is there a better way, so it stays sorted? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

#### This is standard behavior.

The sort you are performing is a point in time.  It is not dynamic and will not re-sort because you edit data.  The same goes for filtering.

1. You can manually resort/refilter (as you noted)
2. You can separate the sorted data from the data source and use a formula to sort the and filter the data dynamically which will cause it to update on changes (not ideal if you want to sort and filter while editing the source data)
3. You can add some Google Apps Script to your sheet that re-applies filters and sorts based on a trigger of your choosing such as clicking on a particular cell.  This would be more complex but give you more control.